# Ruby inheritance, method not being passed to a child class

Tags: ruby, inheritance, rspec

I've got a ruby exercise, and cannot quite get past one point.
When I run the tests, it throws `undefined method "attribute" for CommentSerializer:Class`.
Though, there is such a method defined in `serializer.rb`, from which it's being inherited.

Am I missing something about inheritance in ruby here?

**Note**: I am neither allowed to add any gems other than the two listed below, nor to modify any file other than `serializer.rb`.

Here are the files:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'pry'
```

app/comment.rb:

```
Comment = Struct.new(:id, :body)
```

app/comment_serializer.rb:

```
require_relative "serializer"

class CommentSerializer < Serializer
  attribute :id
  attribute :body
end
```

app/serializer.rb:

```
class Serializer
  def initialize(object)
    @obj = object
  end

  def serialize
    obj.members.inject({}) do |hash, member|
      hash[member] = obj[member]
      hash
    end
  end

  def attribute(key)
  end

  private

  def obj
    @obj
  end
end
```

spec/comment_serializer_spec.rb:

```
require "date"
require_relative "spec_helper"
require_relative "../app/comment"
require_relative "../app/comment_serializer"

RSpec.describe CommentSerializer do
  subject { described_class.new(comment) }

  let(:comment) do
    Comment.new(1, "Foo bar")
  end

  it "serializes object" do
    expect(subject.serialize).to eq({
      id: 1,
      body: "Foo bar",
    })
  end
end
```

Comment: You've defined an instance method, but you call it in the class context. Did you mean to define a class method? If so, `def self.attribute`.

Comment: Tip: Use `attr_reader` if you need to expose access to something. Having a `private` accessor is kind of pointless, though. Just use the `@` variable directly.

Comment: @tadman I see now. Could you shed some light on when that **attribute :symbol** is being fired?

Comment: @tadman private accessors are actually very useful. If you misspell the name you get a NoMethodError instead of just nil.

Comment: @max You can also expose bugs like that with testing, but sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call something like `attribute` in the *body* of the `class` definition then it happens in the class context *at that exact moment*, as in:

```rb
class Example < Serializer
  # This is evaluated immediately, as in self.attribute(:a) or Example.attribute(:a)
  attribute :a
end
```

There must be a corresponding *class method* to receive that call, as in:

```rb
class Serializer
  def self.attribute(name)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Since you're inheriting that method it will be defined prior to calling it, but that's not the case if you have something like:

```rb
class Example
  attribute :a # undefined method `attribute' for Example:Class (NoMethodError)

  def self.attribute(name)
  end
end
```

The method is defined after it's called, so you get this error. You must either reverse the order, define first, call second, or put it into a parent class.